# Fitting Probability Distribution to Failure Data with discrete, right censored stress

Tags: maximum-likelihood, survival, weibull-distribution, kaplan-meier

I'm a bit unfamiliar with survival analysis and I'm struggling to find examples of the particular problem I wish to tackle (which I don't think is particularly unique actually).

Imagine I'm doing a survival test on a set of 100 smart phones whereby I dunk them in water and record how many survive; I measure $t$ every half hour (not at the time each smart phone failures). I stop the experiment after 10 hours.

So I might end up with data which looks something like this:

$t$   |   Number of Failures at $t_i$ ($d_i$)   |   Number of Survivors ($n_i$)

0.5   |   0   |   100

1.0   |   1   |   99

1.5   |   3   |   96

2.0   |   0   |   96

2.5   |   4   |   92

3.0   |   4   |   88

3.5   |   1   |   87

4.0   |   7   |   80

4.5   |   3   |   77

5.0   |   0   |   77

5.5   |   0   |   77

6.0   |   0   |   77

6.5   |   13   |   64

7.0   |   11   |   53

7.5   |   5   |   48

8.0   |   4   |   44

8.5   |   8   |   36

9.0   |   6   |   30

9.5   |   15   |   15

10.0   |   2   |   13

(Apologies for the formatting of the table)

So I have a few questions about this scenario:

1. There are 13 survivors remaining and another 2 failures at 10 hours. So is this a *right censored* value?
2. Since I was only measuring every half an hour, does that mean every other value measured is *left censored*? For example, when I measured at 1 hour, 1 device had failed; it could have failed at 55 minutes however.
3. From the examples I've seen on the internet (such as Matlab examples, reliawiki.com, etc, generally the right-censored data is flagged. How do I factor in the fact that *all* of my data is censored (left or right).
4. Also from the examples I've seen, it seems pretty straight forward to do a *Kaplan-Meier estimate* from this data. How do I extend this approach to fitting various probability distributions.

Caveat: Quite a lot of examples I've seen ([Matlab](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/analyzing-survival-or-reliability-data.html), [Engineering Statistics Handbook](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/apr/section4/apr413.htm), [Reliawiki](http://reliawiki.org/index.php/Non-Parametric_Life_Data_Analysis), [Reliawiki MLE](http://reliawiki.org/index.php/Maximum_Likelihood_Estimation#Maximum_Likelihood_Estimation_.28MLE.29)) handle similar problems, but are different in their own way. Some suggest that the time is measured at the point of each failure, others are more similar to my problem. This leads to my final question:

5. I also understand that when it comes to fitting probability distributions, the maximum likelihood estimation is used i.e., the parameters which maximise likelihood best describe the data. However, all the examples I've seen are in terms of Suspension/Failure data, of the form:
   $L(\vec{\theta}) = \prod_{i=1}^R f(t_i,\vec{\theta}) \cdot \prod_{j=1}^M F(s_j,\vec{\theta}) $
   where $R$ is the total number of failures, $M$ is the number of suspensions, $t_i$ is the time of $i$th failure, $s_j$ is the time of the $j$th suspension, $f$ is the probability density function with parameters $\vec{\theta}$ and $F$ is the cumulative density function with parameters $\vec{\theta}$. How do I account for the fact that multiple failures/suspensions occur at a given time (i.e. 11 failures at 7 hours).

Hopefully that makes sense, I'd really appreciate suggestions or links to various books/articles which I can read.

Again, sorry for formatting issues.

Comment: You are not going to get a good fit to a known smooth distribution.  In particular, no failures between $4.5$ and $6.5$ hours followed by $24$ failures between $6.5$ hours and $7.5$ hours means the results are not smooth

Comment: It's just data I made up on the spot. I suppose if I wanted to generate a rigorous example I would've sampled from a pre-calculated Hazard function. I think the questions still stand however.